# The import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use the notification in an Android app, I found many tuto but all use the  com.google.android.gcm pakage which are deprecated. I see that I have to use the com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging pakage...
but I don't succeed to import this package.

- I already download all the stuff from the SDK manager
- In the Properties project I chose the Project Build target: Google APIs (17)
- In the build path I check also the Google APIs.

and I always have the same error: The import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved

Did I forget to add a jar or an other file I miss?

thanks

**edit:**
I miss this page with the informations (give in the other discution above) for the setup:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

I just don't copy the lib of Google Play.

Comment: did you added gcm.jar file to your project

Comment: something I don't understood: I saw many tuto using the com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar package, but here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html I see that this package is DEPRECATED and that we have to use GoogleCloudMessaging (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html). But when you are in eclipse wile using the GCMRegistrar, you don't have the common warning 'deprecated'. did I miss something? did I just have to use GCMRegistrar? and forget what it is writing on the http://developer.android.com?

Answer (score 6):

Whether you added gcm.jar in your project?

Go to Android SDK Manager->Extras->GCM. Downlad it. Go to particular location.

It will contain gcm.jar.Add in your project.

Excellent tutorial is given here

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I already have the gcm.jar, but in this one I only have the deprecated class GCMBaseIntentService, GCMBroadcastReceiver,GCMConstants and GCMRegistrar, and it's the GoogleCloudMessaging class I would like to use.

Comment: Add jar in your libs-> Add to build path.it will work.

Comment: I have the gcm.jar in the lib folder and in the build path, but in this jar I don't have the GoogleCloudMessaging package (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html), and yes I see that the GCMRegistar class work but I dont understood why here it is write that this class is deprecated (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html)

Comment: I know the tutorial you give, a realy good one

Comment: @Shadow i am trying to create app that work like gmail as the message comes from the server it show it as a notification see this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571844/gcm-not-sending-the-notifications/18572611?noredirect=1#comment27328335_18572611

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `GCM library`y to work with `GCM`. You need to put `GCM` jar file in your `libs` folder and then you have to add it in you project.
To get GCM library and add it to your project look at this link :

[Getting Started with GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Comment: I already have the gcm.jar, but in this one I only have the deprecated class GCMBaseIntentService, GCMBroadcastReceiver,GCMConstants and GCMRegistrar, and it's the GoogleCloudMessaging class I would like to use.

Comment: Copy the JAR file in your libs folder.
Then right click on GCM jar file and Select Build Path --> Add to BUild path.

Comment: I have the gcm.jar in the lib folder and in the build path, but in this jar I don't have the GoogleCloudMessaging package (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html), and yes I see that the GCMRegistar class work but I dont understood why here it is write that this class is deprecated (http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html)